# make a file with the space in its name inaccessible in the cpanel using bash command

Tags: bash, centos, cpanel, quoting

I'm installing a watcher system for my server, this will basically watch my directories for any change/delete/modify/create ... so I can call a `.sh` file in the watcher when those events occur so I have these in my watcher.sh file

```
 #!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/etc/watcher.log
chmod 000 -R $1
chown root $1
echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d);$(date +%H:%M:%S);$1;$3;$2;watcher.sh" >> $LOGFILE
```

It works fine when I upload a file called `a.txt` but if I upload a file with space in their names nothing happens. In the log file I have

```
2017-06-04;18:37:34;/home/domain/public_html/upload/a b.txt;IN_CREATE;128;watcher.sh
chmod: cannot access `/home/domain/public_html/upload/a': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `b.txt': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/home/domain/public_html/upload/a': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `b.txt': No such file or directory
```

the space in the name is messing this up. How can I fix this? Also why can I still delete the newly uploaded file from cpanel I tough by changing ownership to root it would be inaccessible in the cpanel.

Comment: Did you ever hear about "word splitting"? If not, run, don't walk, to your shell manual and read about quoting with double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may place quote characters around the parameters such as:

```
chmod 000 -R "$1"
chown root "$1"
```

The quotes should resolve the issue with the spaces via the parameters in the shell script.